# Passing arguments from root to sub-query in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, graphql

I am sending in an argument (companyId) to my root query. I have a resolver where the query does not need this argument, but the sub-queries do. I have this function where I am adding the data to dataValues and then trying to return it, but this is not working but seems as though it should. If I print out questions I see companyId there, but it is not being passed as a result to my QuestionType for subsequent display.

```
questions: {
      type: new GraphQLList(QuestionType),
      args: {
        companyId: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        }
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return connection.models.question.findAll({
          order: [ ['questionCategoryId', 'ASC'], ['orderPlacement', 'ASC']]
        }).then((questions) => {
          for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            questions[i].dataValues.companyId = parseInt(args.companyId)
          }
          return questions
        })
      }
    }
```

Is there a better way to pass an argument from the root query to a subsequent one, where the argument is not used at the root level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours... This worked I just needed to add a resolver and return parent.dataValues.companyId